# Can the start be "the other end"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

The sentence is " There is the letter T in the end of the word and the letter C in the other end". Can you call the start of the word the other end?

Comment: Its not clear what you are asking.  Did you read this sentence somewhere, and want help to understand it? If so, where did you read it.  If you wrote it yourself, you should try to re-write it using "start", as that would be much clearer.

Comment: Can you? Yes.  Should you?  Probably not, because it confuses the meaning of the word "end".  Why not just write it the other way around?  *There is a letter C at the start of the word, and a T at the **other end**"*   e.g. *carrot*

Comment: I am afraid I thought of a word, and it isn't carrot.

Comment: Would I be right in thinking this is a spoken thing (especially if it's the word I'm thinking of) to describe somebody in a slightly less obvious manner than just saying the word? If so, yes, you could say it like that.

Comment: The first and last letter in a word. The letter T is located **at** the beginning of the word.

Answer (score 1):

The idiom is "one end" and "the other end."

You can omit "one end" only if you specified it earlier in conversation or context can fill in the details.

The "start" will always be whatever is the "one end".

This idiom is used for very long things, so you are implying this word is extremely long (it may be painted on a long billboard, for example).

> There is the letter T in one end of the word and the letter C in the other end.